# How to set limit to a control of being added?

Tags: c#, methods

I tried to set a limit number for a specific control when i added it using method

The code works without if statement perfect (but unlimited)
i want to set limit to 6 only

Simply, All what i wanted is to check the total count of buttons inside a panel
All I was missing is .Count() after OfType<>
It is already answered thanks

```
public void Add(Panel container)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    // size , location , text ,....etc OK
    void  AddMyControl()
    { 
     container.Controls.Add(b);
    }
    foreach(Button i in container.Controls.OfType<Button>()
    { 
      if (i.Controls.Count <=6)
         { 
           AddMyControl();
          }
      else
         {
          return;
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Please update your post so that it includes a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a _precise_ explanation of what that code does now, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void AddButton(Panel container)
 {
    const int maxAllowedButtons = 6;
    int existingButtonCount = container.Controls.OfType<Button>().Count();
    if (existingButtonCount < maxAllowedButtons)
    {
        Button newButton = new Button();
        newButton.Left = newButton.Width * existingButtonCount; // set left position so buttons do not draw on top of each other
        container.Controls.Add(newButton);
     }

 }
```

Comment: lol..All i was missing is .Count() after OfType .Thanks man it works well